# Is it possible to extract the music from Chime?

Tags: chime

I'm playing Chime (via Steam), and the music (before coverage) seems very soothing.

Is it possible to extract it (in the same way as, say, the Portal soundtrack can be found amongst the application files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been looking at some of the files with a hex editor.  It appears that there is no single "*soundtrack*" to the game, but that the game stores the songs in many pieces and assembles them in real-time depending on what's going on in the game.  The song **Still Alive** is in 42 parts itself, with all the data in one file (Portal_Backing.xwb), and the allocation table in another (Portal_Backing.xsb).  I have no idea what format the actual song parts are stored in.

Sorry but it doesn't look like you'll be able to get the songs extracted.

Comment: Makes sense. I could see this being the case with the way the game 'builds' the songs as it goes and as you place pieces, it doesn't really play the songs in their entirety as far as I know.

Comment: Is the menu track as a single file, maybe?  That's the one I'm most interested in...  And it's less likely to be assembled on the fly.

Comment: The menu is also in multiple parts.  I've tried many things but I can't determine what format they're stored in.  It's possible that there is encryption on the data files.

Answer (score 1):

After poking around in the folder, there appear to be no usable sound files.